# I want to rename all the files in a folder with python

Tags: python

```
from glob import glob
from os import rename
import time

arrr = []

def getnames():
    with open("name.txt", "r+") as nameFile:
        for name in nameFile:
            nameFile.readline()
            newlinestrip = name.strip("\n")
            arrr.append(newlinestrip)
        renames()

def renames():
    for fname in glob('*.png'):
        print(fname)
        for name in arrr:
            time.sleep(1)
            rename(fname, name)
            print("bruh")


getnames()
```

It renames the 1st file and the it crashes with the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\rename.py", line 24, in <module>
    getnames()
  File ".\rename.py", line 13, in getnames
    renames()
  File ".\rename.py", line 20, in renames
    rename(fname, name)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet: 'sans (100).png' -> 'acacia_door_top.png'
```

And i don't know how to fix this, i have a txt file with the new names that looks something like this

name.png

name1.png

and so on.

Comment: Why do you have a `sleep(1)` inside the loop?

Comment: How many files do you have that need to be renamed? and what is the count of `arr`?

Comment: i have about 608 file that needs to be renamed, and the count of arr is also 608

Comment: You shouldn't nest the for-loops, use "zip" to pair one source file to one target file name. Due to the nesting you try to rename one source file to every name in the target list but this works only once.

Answer (score 0):

On way is to use `zip()` function if the len of both the files and `arr` is equal, However you could just the following if the intention is to rename all the files with names like `name1.png`, `name2.png` .. `name608.png`:

```
import os
for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir("someDir")):
    dst = "name" + str(count) + ".png"
    src = 'someDir' + filename
    dst = 'someDir' + dst
    # rename() function will rename all the files
    os.rename(src, dst)
```